# Is there a version of laravel for console app only?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-artisan

Currently I am using Symfony console for my terminal apps but I found Laravel artisan console has a lot of features out of the box that I can use. Is there a version of Laravel that has no other command used for developing web apps? or at least to remove default available commands that are registered when you install Laravel?

Comment: You can probably get `illuminate/console` up and running on its own.

Comment: @ceejayoz i will definitely try this. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout [this Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan), where you can define the console commands in form of *Laravel Routes* in **routes/console.php**

Comment: In case you come from google as me I found this framework https://laravel-zero.com/

Answer (score 8):

I've just got this working using `illuminate/console`:

## `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/console": "^5.4",
        "illuminate/container": "^5.4",
        "illuminate/events": "^5.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Yourvendor\\Yourproject\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

## `your-console-app` (replacement for `artisan`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Application;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

use Yourvendor\Yourproject\Console\Commands\Yourcommand;

if (file_exists($a = __DIR__.'/../../autoload.php')) {
    require_once $a;
} else {
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
}

$container = new Container;
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher;
$version = "5.4"; // Laravel version

$app = new Application($container, $dispatcher, $version);

$app->add(new Yourcommand);

$app->run();
```

## `src/Console/Commands/Yourcommand.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Yourvendor\Yourproject\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Yourcommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'yourcommand:test {test}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Yourcommand test';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Hello world!');
    }
}
```

Run the console command using:

## `php your-console-app yourcommand:test`

Comment: awesome! even if i am using python i will definitely try this out. :)

Comment: One thing I just found is that it doesn't seem to be possible to load service providers, so I just switched from `Illuminate\Console\Application` to `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` which has the required `register()` method.